# Delete the first elements of each row in list in python2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7

My list looks like:
['0 0.690001', '1 0.970671', '2 1.520989', '3 1.946516', '4 2.229378']

how can I get 
[ 0.69000,0.970671,1.520989,1.946516,2.229378]

Comment: `[float(string.split()[1]) for string in input_list]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use list comprehension as:

```
my_list = ['0 0.690001', '1 0.970671', '2 1.520989', '3 1.946516', '4 2.229378']
[float(item.split()[1]) for item in my_list]
```

OR, you may also use `map()`:

```
map(lambda x: float(x.split()[1]), my_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import re    
map(lambda x:float(re.sub(r'[^ ]+ ','',x)),l)
```